# add viewpager to tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I have the code here with tabs and It works when you select each tab but I cannot swipe to go to next tab.
Each tab has listview which has its own activity.Only thing I want is to add swipe gesture to go to next tab.How do I do that? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
public class AndroidTabAndListView extends TabActivity {
    // TabSpec Names
    private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Inbox";
    private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Outbox";
    private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Profile";

    ViewPager pager;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


           pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Inbox Tab
        TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
        // Tab Icon
        inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_inbox));
        Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
        // Tab Content
        inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

        // Outbox Tab
        TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
        outboxSpec.setIndicator(OUTBOX_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_outbox));
        Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, OutboxActivity.class);
        outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);

        // Profile Tab
        TabSpec profileSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
        profileSpec.setIndicator(PROFILE_SPEC, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_profile));
        Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        profileSpec.setContent(profileIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); // Adding Inbox tab
        tabHost.addTab(outboxSpec); // Adding Outbox tab
        tabHost.addTab(profileSpec); // Adding Profile tab
    }
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="409dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>



    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: can you provide your `layout.xml` code?

Comment: updated the code.I just want to add swipe feature to next tab .Thats all.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allright I see that you are not using the `ViewPager` in the xml. Because I have not tried it the way you are doin it, I recommend it will be a lot easier if you do it like the following examples:
[Creating Swipe Views with Tabs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)
[Android Tab Layout with Swipeable Views](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)
Still not useful then you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804949/swipe-with-tab-host/15805156#15805156)
Hope it Helps you. Cheers :)

Comment: I tried using fixed tabs+swipe but how do I use intent within : `Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, OutboxActivity.class);
        outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);`   PLease help me out with this I am really confused but I like the intent part as I have 3 custom listview in each activity and I would like that to be on the viewholder but I dont know how tp do that either .Can you shed some light on that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use fragments for inner pages.
Create a class that extends FragmentPagerAdapter for tab buttons.

Example :

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

AndroidTabAndListView.java

```
public class AndroidTabAndListView extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    TabSpecNames mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new TabSpecNames(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
        // parent.
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
                // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
                // Tab.
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    public static class TabSpecNames extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public TabSpecNames(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {

            switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new InboxFragment();
            case 1:
                return new OutboxFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ProfileFragment();
            default:
                break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String sections[] = {"Inbox", "Outbox", "Profile"};
            return sections[position];
        }
    }

}
```

fragment_inbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:text="Inbox (99)"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

InboxFragment.java

```
public class InboxFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, 
                container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code but where do I pass intent . `public static class ContentFragment extends Fragment {   @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main2, container, false);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            String content = args.getString("section_content");
           ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(content);
            return rootView;}}`:::::::::: how do I convert existing activities with custom adapter in here??

Comment: You can't use intent. Just instantiate the fragment class. Fragments must always be embedded in an activity. AndroidTabAndListView is extended from FragmentActivity and it will contain your child fragments. You should convert your existing activities into fragments. See my edited answer.