# How to create intent in a TabActivity

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-fragments, tabs

With `Android Studio` I started a new project based on the default `ActionBar Tab + Swipe Views` but now I want to be able to create `Intents` in the classes I created for the tab's layout but there's no response from the `Button` I click. Do you know why?
Here some code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener, android.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
CollectionPagerAdapter mCollectionPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mCollectionPagerAdapter = new CollectionPagerAdapter(
        getSupportFragmentManager());

final android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.tab_color)));
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mCollectionPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

        });
for (int i = 0; i < mCollectionPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(mCollectionPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
            .setTabListener(this));

}

      }

      public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

       }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

     }

     public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

       }

       @Override
     public void onTabSelected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

   }

      @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

       }

      @Override
     public void onTabReselected(android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

       }

  public class CollectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int NUM_ITEMS = 11; // number of tabs

public CollectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override

public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    Fragment fragment = new TabFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(TabFragment.ARG_OBJECT, i);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return NUM_ITEMS;

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    String tabLabel = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label1);
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label2);
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label3);
            break;
        case 3:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label4);
            break;
        case 4:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label5);
            break;
        case 5:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label6);
            break;
        case 6:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label7);
            break;
        case 7:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label8);
            break;
        case 8:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label9);
            break;
        case 9:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label10);
            break;
        case 10:
            tabLabel = getString(R.string.label11);
            break;


    }

    return tabLabel;

}
}

public static class TabFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    int position = args.getInt(ARG_OBJECT);
    int tabLayout = 0;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab1;
            break;
        case 1:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab2;
            break;
        case 2:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab3;
            break;
        case 3:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab4;
            break;
        case 4:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab5;
            break;
        case 5:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab6;
            break;
        case 6:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab7;
            break;
        case 7:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab8;
            break;
        case 8:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab9;
            break;
        case 9:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab10;
            break;
        case 10:
            tabLayout = R.layout.tab11;
            break;

    }

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(tabLayout, container, false);
    return rootView;

 }
```

and my 5th tab's class:

```
public class Tab5Activity extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab5, container, false);

}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Button button1 = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          //do something
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the tab text in onTabSelected method.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    if (tab.getText().equals(getString(R.string.label5) )) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Tab5Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        return;
    }
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you know how to show this layout under the tab? I mean when I swipe to the 5th layout It opens a new activity that works but there's no more the tab.

Comment: Like you can see in the Google Play App

Comment: You mean showing Tab5Activity under your FragmentActivity ?

Comment: Yes, the functions that does the tab5Activity under the Tab , without opening a new activity  where there isn't the Tab

Comment: Your pages can only be extended from fragment. If you want your Tab5Activity to be included in ViewPager, extend Tab5Activity from Fragment instead of FragmentActivity.

Comment: I changed to Fragment but the app crashes. See my edits to see how my Tab5Activity now

Comment: If you want to show a fragment under ViewPager, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601018/add-viewpager-to-tabs/21601885#21601885 But if you want to open a new **activity** when Tab button pressed, then use onTabSelected method (use activity)