# Android Swipe in Tabhost

Tags: java, android

How can i implement Swipe between my tabs in tabhost thank you, following is my xml file and java file.

Please help me to implement swipe in this tabhost , Some one know more about tabhost kindly share allthe tabhost options.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bRecharge">

    </FrameLayout>
</TabHost>
```

java file

```
package com.veristics.tijo.smartrecharge;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.veristics.san.smartrecharge.net.AsyncNetCall;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends TabActivity{
float lastX;
AsyncNetCall asyncNetCall;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec mobile = tabHost.newTabSpec("Mobile");
    mobile.setIndicator("mobile");
    Intent mob = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MobileActivity.class);
    mobile.setContent(mob);

    TabHost.TabSpec dth = tabHost.newTabSpec("DTH");
    dth.setIndicator("DTH");
    Intent d = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DTHActivity.class);
    dth.setContent(d);

    TabHost.TabSpec datacard = tabHost.newTabSpec("Datacard");
    datacard.setIndicator("datacard");
    Intent dc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DataCardActivity.class);
    datacard.setContent(dc);

    tabHost.addTab(mobile);
    tabHost.addTab(dth);
    tabHost.addTab(datacard);

    ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_actionbar, null);

    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    new AsyncNetCall(this).execute("getUserBalance");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_account_log:
            Intent account_log = new   Intent(this,AccountLogActivity.class);
            startActivity(account_log);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_recharge_log:
            Intent recharge = new Intent(this,RechargeLogActivity.class);
            startActivity(recharge);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_logout:
            Intent login = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please take a look into this question., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843479/android-tabs-without-actionbar

Comment: Swipe using tab host is not recommended. Use view pager adapter. http://codetheory.in/android-swipe-views-with-tabs/

Comment: Thank  @Madhukar Hebbar you but i need to implement swipe in tabhost ..

Comment: Try this 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20322761/4596556
TabHost:
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Tabs-with-swipe-effect-on-Android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*@Tijo John :*

**Bad Approach**

1. Using Deprecated Code [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

> This class was deprecated in API level 13. New applications should use
>   Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices,
>   you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the
>   Fragment API

**Best Way**

1. Use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) or [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html)

> ViewPager is most often used in conjunction with Fragment, which is a
>   convenient way to supply and manage the lifecycle of each page. There
>   are standard adapters implemented for using fragments with the
>   ViewPager, which cover the most common use cases.

[Demo](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Tabs-with-swipe-effect-on-Android)